# How to produce a dynamic file xml with registry keys?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to produce a dynamic xml file with all values from my registry key

example : this code can read the registry key

```
Dim mod64 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = 
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey 
       (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64)

Dim UID As String = mod64.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\PROVA.NET\DB_CONF").GetValue("UID")
Dim PASS As String = mod64.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\PROVA.NET\DB_CONF").GetValue("PWD")
```

I want to produce a dynamic xml file. When I add key to my registry another node should be created in my xml

thanks

Comment: Dont store passwords in the registry; especially not prominently labled "PWD" and especially not as plain text

Comment: "I want" is not question!  These are questions:  "What have you tried?  How is the code you tried not fulfilling your objectives?  Why have you not shown us what you have tried?"

Comment: there are many ways to write XML file. But if you want to have it updated when registry is, you need to write a service to do that.

Comment: i want to create a function that read dynamically  all the key in my registry and create xml file .